# ¿Que es mas optimo para retornar un valor?

Tags: php

Desde hace tiempo que me eh preguntado que es más optimo en una función `php` para hacer un `return` de un valor.

Tengo la función que recibe un parámetro `string` y ese lo compara dentro de `if`, mi duda surge en si es más optimo que dentro de cada `if` tenga un `return` para que cuando entre al `if` enseguida retorne el valor y ya no verifique los demás o es mejor que tenga el `return` después de todas las condiciones.

Así como también pudiese hacer uso de `elseif` para que cuando entre a alguna `condición` ya no entre a las demás, pero aquí también aplicaría el poner el `return` dentro de la condición o ponerlo al final de todas las condiciones.

Las funciones de ejemplo son pequeñas (2 condiciones) pero las que voy a utilizar en un proyecto son de muchas condiciones y de ahí surge la necesidad de encontrar el método óptimo.

**Función #1:**

```
private function obtener_assets($parametro)
{
    if ($parametro == 'compras'){
        $data = array(
            'assets/js/scripts/pages/compras.js',
        );
    }
    if ($parametro == 'pagos'){
        $data = array(
            'assets/js/scripts/pages/pagos.js',
        );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

**Función #2:**

```
private function obtener_assets($parametro)
{
    if ($parametro == 'compras'){
        $data = array(
            'assets/js/scripts/pages/compras.js',
        );
        return $data;
    }
    if ($parametro == 'pagos'){
        $data = array(
            'assets/js/scripts/pages/pagos.js',
        );
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**Función #3:**

```
private function obtener_assets($parametro)
{
    if ($parametro == 'compras'){
        $data = array(
            'assets/js/scripts/pages/compras.js',
        );
    }
    elseif ($parametro == 'pagos'){
        $data = array(
            'assets/js/scripts/pages/pagos.js',
        );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

**Función #4:**

```
private function obtener_assets($parametro)
{
    if ($parametro == 'compras'){
        $data = array(
            'assets/js/scripts/pages/compras.js',
        );
        return $data;
    }
    elseif ($parametro == 'pagos'){
        $data = array(
            'assets/js/scripts/pages/pagos.js',
        );
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por optimo te referis a que es mas lindo visualmente? porque en todos los casos, el codigo hace exactamente lo mismo...

Comment: @gbianchi no me refiero a lo bonito, me refiero al tiempo de procesamiento, al tiempo que requiere hacer esa acción, porque no es lo mismo hacer uso de 2 condiciones a hacer uso de 50.

Comment: Entonces ninguna de las respuestas que te estan dando se correponden con lo que estas preguntando. Porque se necesitaria un benchmark de cada una, y solo te estan contestando sobre lo "bonito" del codigo

Comment: @gbianchi nadie está contestando sobre lo bonito del código, se está contestando sobre la eficiencia de este, la forma más simple y rápida de hacerlo. Creo que aún no entiendes el concepto.

Comment: Nadie esta midiendo la eficiencia del codigo. Todos los codigos que te pasaron, llegan al mismo objetivo. Para medir eficiencia, deberias medir la cantidad de instrucciones ejecutadas para llegar a tu objetivo, y eso se hace con un benchmark. Tal vez, vos estas buscando menos lineas, y a eso me refiero con bonito, y por eso te pregunte que era exactamente lo que pedias. Nadie en ninguna de las respuesta esta midiendo si el caso 1 es mas rapido que el 2 o que el switch o que un operador ternario.

Comment: Está preguntando sobre la eficiencia de cada método , cuál sería más veloz a la hora de ejecutarlo. Porfavor lee la pregunta de nuevo y te darás cuenta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo optaría por una solución mucho más simple y más portable que consiste en lo siguiente:

- Manejar una verdadera estructura de datos dentro de la función (o de la clase si fuera preciso), mediante un array.
- Pasar el valor a la función y buscarlo dentro del array si lo encuentra, o devolver un valor por defecto.

Haciendo esto, cuando haya nuevos assets, sólo lo agregas al array y no tienes que modificar `if` o bloques `switch ... case` que podrían ser interminables.

Este sería el código:

```
function obtener_assets($parametro)
{
    $allAssets= 
        array ( 
                'compras' => 'assets/js/scripts/pages/compras.js',
                'pagos'   => 'assets/js/scripts/pages/pagos.js',
              );

    $asset= ( isset($allAssets[$parametro]) ) ? $allAssets[$parametro] : "no asset";
    return $asset;
}
```

Hacemos algunas pruebas:

```
echo obtener_assets('pagos').PHP_EOL;
echo obtener_assets('compras').PHP_EOL;
echo obtener_assets('fake').PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
assets/js/scripts/pages/pagos.js
assets/js/scripts/pages/compras.js
no asset
```

---

#### Fiddle

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[`DEMOSTRACIÓN`](https://rextester.com/NMPJGB17896)**</kbd> del código y hacer ensayos con él.

---

> **NOTA:**
>
> El ejemplo mostrado aquí está basado en un array simple, si tuvieras
> una estructura más compleja también sería posible, sería cuestión de
> adaptarlo al modelo de datos.
>
> Si tus datos estuvieran por ejemplo en una base de datos hacer esto es
> mucho más acorde con tu el entorno, ya que el array se puede llenar
> por ejemplo desde una consulta a la base de datos, incluso si fueran
> tablas relacionadas.

Comment: Si algo es cierto es que haciendo uso de la condicional ternaria lo único que tendría que estar llenando serían los `assets` dentro del arreglo, aunque estén anidados y únicamente retornar el que sea de mi interés. ¡Excelente respuesta Gracias!

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado correcto. El que los datos estén anidados o no es indiferente en cuanto a la lógica explicada en este enfoque, sólo habría que modificar la forma de buscar el dato dentro de la estructura. Además es una solución más realista, porque tu array representa en sí una entidad o un miembro de tu aplicación que llamaremos *losAssets*, lo puedes incorporar como miembro de una clase, reutilizarlo en múltiples contextos, etc. O sea, donde quiera que vayas a hacer algo con *losAssets* utilizas este objeto. Y si lo creas desde la BD, tienes siempre un estado real de las cosas.

Comment: En efecto, estoy creando un `Library` para `Codeigniter` y me va a servir demasiado hacer uso de dicha solución. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Yo me aventuraría a darte otra opción adicional a las que expones. Es semejante (practicamente) a un anidamiento de `if` (como el que expones en **Función:#4**) en cuanto a optimización se refiere, pero tiene el aliciente añadido de ser mucho más eficiente a nivel visual:

**Función #5:**

```
private function obtener_assets($parametro)
{
    switch ($parametro) {
         case 'compras':
                return array (
                    'assets/js/scripts/pages/compras.js',
                );
         case 'pagos':
                return array (
                    'assets/js/scripts/pages/pagos.js',
                );
    }    
}
```

Además los `switch` tienen la propiedad de que son muy fáciles de añadir nuevas condiciones, a si que son muy sencillos de adaptar cuando crece el número de estas.

Comment: Tienes razón en cuanto a la forma más fácil de agregar nuevas condiciones, según [phpbench.com](http://phpbench.com/) es más rápido usar `if/else/elseif` que `switch/case` únicamente cuando se hace uso de comparación estricta. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

**#1 y #3** Tienen un error, en caso que `$parametro` no tenga ninguno de los valores la función tratará de retornar una variable que nunca existió ( Por qué la declaración estaba dentro de las condicionales ), recuerda que debes blindar tu código por más absurdo que sea, no conoces los límites del usuario final.

```
<?php

function func ( $param ){
    if ( $param == 'foo' ){
        $data = array('isFoo');
    }
    if ( $param == 'bar' ) {
        $data = array('isBar');
    }
    return $data;
}

print_r( func('poo') );
?>
```

Las otras propuestas son válidas, esto es gusto de cada developer y también casos esenciales, si la función ya no hará nada más allá de regresar una variable armada, está excelente, pero, si después de las condicionales hay más líneas por ejecutar, estas nunca se verán reflejadas por que estás "cortando el código"

```
<?php

function func ( $param ){
    if ( $param == 'foo' ){
        return $data = array('isFoo');
    }
    elseif ( $param == 'bar' ) {
        return $data = array('isBar');
    }
    array_push( $data, 'loaded!' );
}

print_r( func('foo') );

?>
```

Ahora si las condicionales son muchas, entonces utiliza un `switch` como recomendó @PHPMyguel puesto que no se evalúan todas las condiciones si no es un trato directo (Es raro por que python no utiliza switch)

```
<?php

function func ( $param ){
    switch( $param ){
        case 'foo':
            return array( 'isFoo' );
        break;

        case 'bar':
            return array('isBar');
        break;

        default:
            return null;
        break;
    }
}

print_r( func('bar') );

?>
```

Si es una condición entre 2 opciones entonces una condicional ternaria, obviamente a nivel de procesamiento es la más rápida

```
<?php

function func ( $param ){
    return $param == 'foo' ? array('isFoo') : array('isBar');
}

print_r( func('bar') );

?>
```

Todas las opciones son válidas siempre y cuando sepas cómo y cuando utilizarlas y también un poco de "Buen gusto".

Comment: Excelente respuesta, me quedo bastante claro y buen punto el de retornar nada en caso de no entrar a ninguna condición, me quedo con el `switch` haciendo uso de `default` y la condición ternaria para condiciones pequeñas. ¡Gracias!