# Error con funciones en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo a usar funciones y trate de hacer una para identificar las prioridades de una lista de notas. Tengo este codigo:

```
<?php
function prioridades() {
if($rows['prioridad'] == "1") {
echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-cate-normal">Normal</span>';
} elseif($rows['prioridad'] == "2") {
    echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-cate-medium">Medium</span>';
} elseif($rows['prioridad'] == "3") {
    echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-cate-urgent">Urgent</span>';
} else {
    echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">Prioritys</span>';
}
}
?>
```

Lo que trato de hacer es colocar todas las funciones dentro de un .php y llamarlas segun sea necesario. Esta funcion esta guardad en block.php y en el index hago lo siguiente:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'funciones/block.php';
?>

//codigo HTML

<?php
$ls = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM notas WHERE notascode = '".$row_u['codde']."'");
while ($rows = $ls->fetch()) {
?>

// lista de notas (codigo html)

<?php
prioridades(); // llamo a la prioridad
} // fin del while
?>
```

El error es que como resultado me arroja: `<span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">Prioritys</span>`, pero en la base de datos la prioridad de la nota es `1` que es `normal`.

No se donde esta el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas pasar el parametro `$rows` a tu funcion.  Algo asi:

```
prioridades($rows);
```

Y en tu declaracion:

```
function prioridades($rows) {
```

Comment: Era solo es!? Estuve toda la noche tratando de resolverlo. Entonces cada vez que haga este tipo de funciones tendre que tener en cuenta eso. Muchas gracias, me has salvado!

Comment: @previant para evitar repetición de código y tener un programa más portable, puedes usar un array asociativo con valores como `1=>normal, 2=>medium, 3=>urgent`... así sólo buscar por la clave numérica sin tener que usar tres o cuatro o `n` `if`. Obtienes todo con una sola línea y si en el futuro se agrega otra opción sólo tienes que añadirla al array ([aquí hay un ejemplo de lo que digo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/237294/29967) explicado en otro contexto).

Comment: Entiendo, voy a aprender a implementar lo que me dices. Si bien tengo el ejemplo, solo me falta aplicarlo. Lo primero que fue en modo de prueba se resolvio, me faltaria implementar lo que me dices del `array`. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @previant no será difícil implementarlo, además ayuda a tener el código ordenado y programar de forma coherente. Por ejemplo hay un caso en tu código que será un escollo y que debería normalizar. Todo está OK, hasta que llegamos aquí: `echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">Prioritys</span>'` ¿por qué ahí la clase no se llama `prioritys` o la opción se llama `Dark`? Es cierto que eso se puede resolver en la lógica de la función, indicando que cuando sea `Prioritys` asigne la clase `dark`. Fíjate que puedes construir tanto el nombre de la clase como el texto del span de forma dinámica.

Comment: En caso de no haber categoria coloque eso  `echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">Prioritys</span>'` a modo de entender que hay algun dato.

Answer (score 0):

Las variables declaradas fuera no son tratadas como globales, para usarla en una función tienes que hacerlo con `global` o pasarle la variable a la función. [Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php) hay mas información sobre el ámbito de las variables.

```
<?php

function prioridades() ó // prioridades($rows)
{
    global $rows;
    ...
}

prioridades();    
?>
```

Comment: El uso de globales es considerado por lo general una mala práctica. En este caso es evidente que complicarse la vida con globales está de más, sería una pésima implementación.